# Why I can not use customeTextField?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Here are some codes that I can not use them in javafx what should I do?

```
<CustomTextField fx:id="fieldSearch" styleClass="searchField">
    <left>
        <Label styleClass="searchBoxLabel">
            <graphic>
                <FontAwesomeIconView styleClass="searchBoxLabelIcon"/>
            </graphic>
        </Label>
    </left>
</CustomTextField>
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/VocabHunter/VocabHunter/blob/1.0.19/gui/src/main/resources/session.fxml) that I want to use it's code for javafx

Comment: What does "I can not use them" mean?

Comment: @James_D if i use the the intelli J idea make them red and do let me to use them it says it can not resolve symbols

Comment: Did you add the import at the top of your fxml?

Comment: @AlexFerretti sorry for my late replay, yes import them but even the intelli J idea make them red some import like <?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your classpath. Do you have every library needed ? Like `controlsfx` and 'FontAwesomeFX` ?

Comment: @AlexFerretti I have copy and paste exactly that github site(the link) but it didn't work  ??!!

Comment: Yeah, usually, copying and pasting won't work nicely, especially when the project depends on other libraries. Add them using Maven or Gradle (if you know how to use it) or add the `.jar` files to your project.
The project owner uses Gradle to import dependencies, so that's why he doesn't have any problem.